# pandas plot x-axis label

Tags: python, pandas, plot, axis-labels

I bumped into a problem when plotting a pandas series.
When plotting the series with a datetime x-axis, x-axis is accordingly relabeled when zooming, i.e. it works fine:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn
from pandas import Series,date_range
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
date_index = date_range('1/1/2016', periods=6*24*7, freq='10Min')
ts = Series(randn(len(date_index)), index=date_index)
ts.plot(); plt.show()
```

However, when i redefine the series index as strings, a strange thing happens, the zoom does not work properly anymore (the limits seem not to change)

```
sindex=np.vectorize(lambda s: s.strftime('%d.%m %H:%M'))(ts.index.to_pydatetime())
ts = Series(randn(len(date_index)), index=sindex)
ts.plot(); plt.show()
```

Is this a bug or do i misuse/misunderstand ? advice/help would be very welcome.

I also noticed that plotting with kind='bar' is comparatively to default incredibly slow (with longer vectors), and i am not sure what would be the origin of that...

Answer (score 0):

When you format your date labels as strings before plotting, you lose all the actual date information; they're just strings now. This means that pandas / matplotlib can't reformat the tick labels when you zoom. See the first paragraph after the plot [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot).

For you second question, bar plot will draw a tick and bar for every data point. For large series this gets expensive. At this time pandas bar plots are not hooked into the auto-formatting like like plot is. You can do a bar plot directly with matplotlib though, and suppress some of the ticks yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then it is a bug that the tick labels are not readjusted. Hopefully this will change somedays.